# C# - read console buffer from earlier started application?

Tags: c#, process, console

Is it possible to read console buffer from a console application which was started earlier?
I assume there's one running instance at a time and I can find it by `Process.GetProcessesByName()` or similar. Can I check, what is already written on its console?

Comment: Windows explicitly blocks that if the console buffer wasn't shared by your program, you can never get to it from the Process class.  That would be a giant security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that point it really has nothing to do with the program, but how it's called.  If it's called from a shell then it depends on whether or not that shell provides means for an external application to access it's current data.  Some might, some might not.  The program may not even be called from a shell at all, it could be called from some other type of program that processes the standard input/output entirely differently from how a shell might.

In general I wouldn't expect most shells to provide a means for other processes to go in and grab it's content, so while it might be possible under certain circumstances, it's unlikely to be a good idea.

Instead you should have the program write the output to some location such as a file, memory mapped file, named pipe, database, etc. which is *designed* to be accessible by another process.

Comment: How about I narrow the possibilities? The program I want to "read" is started from Explorer or Total Commander or with `Process.Start()` from custom program with `UseShellExecute=true`. Anyway, it's console output is not redirected/captured.
Does it help?

Comment: @WRonX Then it uses the OS's default shell, which can still technically vary.  As per the edit, it's unlikely to be feasible, and almost certainly *shouldn't* be done even if it could be.  You should be re-designing what you're doing so that you don't *have* to do this.